# Spacing between columns 'ResponsiveGridLayout' (SAPUI5)

Tags: styles, sapui5, spacing, responsive

How can I reduce the spacing in a `ResponsiveGridLayout`? In this image I want that there is no sapcing betweem the `SearchField` an the `Button`. I've searched via Google and take a close look in the API, but I found nothing.

[image]

EDIT:

```
                var oResponsiveLayout = new sap.ui.layout.form.ResponsiveGridLayout({

        columnsL : 3,
        columnsM : 3,
        columnS : 1
    });
    var oFormLayout = new sap.ui.layout.form.Form({
        layout : oResponsiveLayout,
        formContainers : [ new sap.ui.layout.form.FormContainer({
            formElements : [ new sap.ui.layout.form.FormElement({
                fields : [ this.oSearchField = new sap.ui.commons.SearchField({
                    width : "100%",
                    placeholder : "Suchtext / ID",
                    search : this._onSearchRequest.bind(this),
                    layoutData : new sap.ui.layout.GridData({
                        span : "XL9 L9 M6 S6"
                    })
                }) ]
            }) ]
        }), new sap.ui.layout.form.FormContainer({
            formElements : [ new sap.ui.layout.form.FormElement({
                fields : [ this.oArrowUp = new sap.ui.commons.Button({
                    layoutData : new sap.ui.layout.GridData({
                        span : "XL1 L1 M2 S2"
                    }),
                    width : "100%",
                    icon : "resources/images/arrow_up.png",
                    tooltip : new sap.ui.commons.RichTooltip({
                        text : "Vorheriges Element der Suche anzeigen"
                    }),
                    press : this._onSearchArrowUpRequest.bind(this)
                }), this.oArrowDown = new sap.ui.commons.Button({
                    layoutData : new sap.ui.layout.GridData({
                        span : "XL1 L1 M2 S2"
                    }),
                    width : "100%",
                    icon : "resources/images/arrow_down.png",
                    tooltip : new sap.ui.commons.RichTooltip({
                        text : "Nächstes Element der Suche anzeigen"
                    }),
                    press : this._onSearchArrowDownRequest.bind(this)
                }) ]
            }) ]
        }),
```

Comment: have you tried applying [predefined CSS classes](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_uiaddon10/helpdata/en/77/7168ffe8324873973151dae2356d1c/content.htm) to Button and SerchField control?

Comment: can you provide fiddle/jsbin of what you have done?

Comment: I've added the code in the edit above. I thought that I maybe can avoid to style it via CSS, but when there is no other way I must do it

Comment: Chris, you do know that the Grid is 12 units wide, don't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://jsbin.com/yiriru/3/edit?html,output) is the solution; you can add empty `Label` before `SearchField` and set the labelSpan(M/L/S) according to your need.
It will also be responsive, so you are safe to use it.

Answer (score 1):

**class="sapUiSmallMarginEnd"**

*Use above class in SearchField in the xml view*